# Allow firefox extension to run in private windows via policy engine

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

I'd like to allow certain extensions to run in private windows via firefox's policy engine. I found out that one can set this in `extension-preferences.json`:

```
{
  "uBlock0@raymondhill.net": {
    "permissions": [
      "internal:privateBrowsingAllowed"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried to include this in my `policies.json` similarly to what's described in [here](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#3rdparty)

```
{
  "policies": {
    "ExtensionSettings": {
      "uBlock0@raymondhill.net": {
        "installation_mode": "force_installed",
        "install_url": "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/ublock-origin/latest.xpi"
      }
    },
    "3rdparty": {
      "Extensions": {
        "uBlock0@raymondhill.net": {
          "permissions":["internal:privateBrowsingAllowed"],
          "adminSettings": {
            "selectedFilterLists": [
              "ublock-privacy",
              "ublock-badware",
              "ublock-filters"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, `permissions` doesn't seem to be a valid key (no error message in "about:policies" though) or at least it doesn't have the desired effect: In

about:addons -> uBlock Origin -> Run in Private Windows

the "Don't Allow" radio button is still selected (restarted firefox, recreated profile).

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to enforce extensions running in Incognito mode. There is a discussion about it on [mozilla.org](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/private-browsing-enforcing-use-of-an-extension/35246/3) confirming this. The only option is to disable private browsing mode through policies, which is far from ideal but nothing can be done about it.